# What adjective or phrase can describe that there is a lot of information?

Tags: adjectives

I want to describe that the data contains a lot of information. I am considering

1. lots of information from the data
2. sufficient information from 
   the data
3. large information from the data

Am I correct? Do you have other suggestive adjective or phrase can describe that there is a lot of information?

Another question is that can I say "take advantage by doing something"?

Comment: In the vernacular, we say that there is a _firehose of data._

Comment: "Dense" also works, e.g. "A dense report detailed my expenditures down to the last penny," though it may apply more to literature. Also, you may note that "dense" can also be an insult, as it calls someone stupid.

Answer (score 1):

You could use such words as "**wellspring**", "**depository**" or "**storehouse**":

- The data is a wellspring of information.
- The data is a storehouse/depository of information.

You could use the words "**loads**" or "**rich**":

- The data contains loads of information. (**informal**)
- The data is rich with information.

You could also use "**abundant amount**", "**bucketload**" or "**ocean**":

- The data contains abundant amount of information.
- The data contains a bucketload of information.
- The data contains an ocean of information.

Answer (score 1):

People sometimes refer to data worth looking at as being *[rich.](https://www.google.com/#safe=active&q=%22a+rich+dataset%22)*

With large data sets, you may wish to distinguish between the data that have useful meaning and the data that do not.  In the sciences, the useful part of the data (the information) is often called the *signal,* while the non-useful part of the data is called the *noise.*

We can then refer to the *signal to noise ratio.*  A rich dataset has a high signal to noise ratio, while a data set that is mostly garbage has a low signal to noise ratio.

---

As far as your direct question:

> - large information from the data

I have never heard information described as "large."

> - lots of information from the data

This could be fine - depending on the verb that comes before *lots.*

- *There is [lots / a lot] of information **in** the data.*
- *I extracted [lots / a lot] of information **from** the data.*

I think there is some reason to prefer [a lot of] over [lots of] but I can't remember why.  Both expressions are [very common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lots%20of%2Ca%20lot%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2017&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clots%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20lot%20of%3B%2Cc0)

> - sufficient information from the data

Similar to *a lot of,* in that the choice of preposition depends on the verb. 
 Different in that *sufficient* means *enough,* and is not a synonym of *lots.*

- *We don't know exactly how efficient this new car is, but I was able to extract **sufficient information from the data** to know that it is an improvement on the old design.*